# pywinauto script to add two recipients in new outlook. I am able to add single recipient , but when tried more than one then getting error

Tags: outlook, pywinauto

pywinauto script to add two recipients in new outlook. I am able to add single recipient , but when tried more than one then getting error.

Need pywinauto script to put multiple recipients in new compose mail

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You really need to include the relevant snippet of your code as well as the complete error details.